# Has criminal-related research been conducted regarding critical childhood experiences/adverse turning points for individuals who commit murder?

Tags: learning, criminology, children

I've conducted some basic research regarding criminology and the work of criminal psychologists.  From what I've concluded, the focus of these studies are primarily related to determining why specific crimes are committed by individuals as well as identifying factors that are associated with crimes that have been committed or individual's actions, behavior, etc. related to a crime.

I'd like to understand if research has been conducted related to the childhood/early life experiences of individuals who have committed murder as an adult to determine which early life experiences they pinpoint as "turning points" which ultimately led them to intentionally kill another human being, etc.

To provide clarification regarding my motivation, I am specifically interested in identifying deficiencies in skills (e.g. anger management, self-control, emotional-regulation, etc.) in adolescents which contribute to life-altering anger-based decisions made by an individual when they are an adult.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  My suspicion is that this question is too broad - ie, too many types of crimes x types of childhood experiences x types of learned skills to explore here.  I recommend narrowing down the scope if possible.

Comment: I am very confident that such research exists and I agree with @ArnonWeinberg here that your questionisvery broad. What will narrow the question immensely would be to ask yourself if there is a particular felony you are interested in? Murder, rape, burglary, kidnapping, arson, selling drugs...? If you are interested in more than one you can ask about each one in separate questions. You are not restricted to a particular number of questions.

Comment: Could you specify (you use the US word "felons") what jurisdiction you might be referring to as different societies naturally produce different outcomes as their response to these things varies greatly for cultural reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback regarding my question.  I have now updated my question to narrow the topic and provide additional clarification.

Comment: I voted to reopen your question after you edited it, but no other reopen votes have been cast that I can see. Looking at your question again it could be due to the fact that you haven't provided prior research information. What have you read and what we're the findings? How are they different to what you are after and what makes you think deficiencies in skills in adolescence contributes to murderous intentions?

Comment: [This meta question](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993) points out that prior research information helps to provide a more useful answer.